# Should I send my content to other websites by RSS Feed?

Tags: duplicate-content, feeds

This is a real estate website with thousants of items published with information and pictures.

There are a lot of other websites where I can send a XML Feed so they will republish the content and give me traffic.

I did collaborate with this websites some time ago but stopped because I was struggling to get some organic traffic and the fact that I was recieveing visits from those websites did not seem to help with anything in increasing the organic traffic.

But I really feel I am missing some customers if I don't send my content to those websites.

What should I do? Keep the content for myself, send it to those websites and risk being penalised for duplicate content/images issues? Try to change the content and send them a modified version of the content?

Anyone who could clarify this issue would be very helpful, I am sure I am not the only one in this situation.

The problem is that I cannot just publish it and see what happens, I need to convince my team members that it is safe and won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the customer acquisition process.

Right now, you're getting a lot more click-throughs from sharing your content, that is bringing users to your website. If you're already listed on the first page of search rankings, then duplicate content may hurt you. If you're not, then optimizing your website just for search engines isn't the only way to pull in clients.

You could maybe try a limited share strategy, where you just share a piece of your content and then ask the reader to read the full thing on your website (which is another strategy, which may not appeal to people republishing your content).

But remember that organic traffic isn't as critical as getting the people who are clicking from other websites to come to yours. Think about it this way, the only people that are actually clicking through are most likely your target market, meaning that they already know what type of website you have and are actively going through to see it. In terms of Search Engines, this isn't always the case, as the content sometimes doesn't match what the person was searching for. With this in mind, you should actually focus on converting those people who are clicking through from other sites into clients, because they are as likely to be your target market.